# Convert list of lists to delimited string

Tags: python, string, list

How do I do the following using built-in modules only?

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[['dog', 1], ['cat', 2, 'a'], ['rat', 3, 4], ['bat', 5]]
```

And from it, I'd like to produce a string representation of a table like this where the columns are delimited by tabs and the rows by newlines.

```
dog 1
cat 2   a
rat 3   4
bat 5
```

i.e.

```
'dog\t1\ncat\t2\ta\nrat\t3\t4\nbat\t5'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this, perhaps:

```
lists = [['dog', 1], ['cat', 2, 'a'], ['rat', 3, 4], ['bat', 5]]
result = "\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in lists)
```

This joins all the inner lists using tabs, and concatenates the resulting list of strings using newlines.

It uses a feature called [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to process the outer list.

Comment: You can also change the second line to: result = '\n'.join('\t'.join(str(el) for el in list) for list in lists)

Answer (score 4):

```
# rows contains the list of lists
lines = []
for row in rows:
    lines.append('\t'.join(map(str, row)))
result = '\n'.join(lines)
```